# "on" in "It's on.", "Let's get it on." and "Bring it on."

Tags: meaning, prepositions

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/its-on.1309774/#post-6671834):
**(1)** It's **on**. = It's **beginning**.
**(2)** Let's get it **on**. = Let's get it **started**.
That is, "on" in (1) and (2) relates to the beginning of something.

Proceeding from it, the origin of "*Bring it on.*" is probably:
**(3)** Bring it **on**. = Bring it **to the beginning**.
Am I right about (3)?
If not, then why not?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bring-it-on, https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+it+on ,

Comment: The ***on*** in ***Bring it on**!* doesn't really "mean" anything. We're not used to omitting the preposition, but ***Bring it**!* is in principle a perfectly valid alternative to ***Let's have it**!* or ***Proceed**!* (with whatever display or process has been prepared).

Answer (score 2):

I fear that you are overly limiting the meanign of these phrases, which are used in a variety of situations.

- "*it's on*" Can me "It is starting" but more often means "It is going ahead. Or It will proceed."  For example: "Is the concert on or off? I heard the singer was ill. / It's on. She got better."
- "*Let's get it on*" probably most often means "Let's engage in sex, or sexual foreplay." In this sense, "on" has to do with "turned on" as a euphemism for "aroused" and has nothing to do with the start of something. "*Let's get it on* can mean "Lets get it started" what ever 'it" might be, but can also mean "lets do something exciting or enjoyable."
- "*Bring it on*"  is often a response to a challenge.  It means "present the challenge" with the implication that the speaker will handle it easily. It means "get started" only in a secondary way, I think.

Comment: My sense of "bring it on" is that it means something similar to "bring it over here" or "bring it to me (and I'll deal with it easily)". It is indeed accepting a challenge, calling for the challenge to be brought over and started ("come here and fight me!").